# How to determine type of nullable attributes on an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a form and a user is filling it out, but I want to allow incomplete forms to be saved.

Before I can send the object to my API, I need to initialize the null attributes to either 0 or empty string depending on whether the type of the attribute is a number or a string, else the object cannot be accepted by the API.

My current solution looks like this:

```
    for (const property in this._object) {
        if (this._object[property] == null) {
            //need help determining if [property] is supposed to be a string or a number
        }
    }
```

As a typeof check does not work on nulls, there is no way to tell the strings and numbers apart. How do I determine the type of an object that is currently null? The properties are all strongly typed in the object class, so typescript knows the type at compile time at least.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't concern itself with runtime type recognition, which is what you're trying to do. You'll have to make-do with `typeof`.

Comment: How are you populating your `_object` from the form? You should be able to do the "`0` or `""`" logic there instead of hacking it with a `for( x in y )` loop.

Comment: well I'm relying on user input, so if the user makes no input, the object is not populated.

Also resetting the form replaces all the bound values with nulls so what I'm doing in the constructor doesn't matter.

Comment: I should add that the reason I need to populate with 0s is that I can't send nulls in my int attributes to my API because ints can't be null. However, strings also can't be 0 so you see my predicament

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible since TypeScript types exist at compile time *only*. Once the code is executing, the types will have already been erased.

The only way to achieve something close to what you are trying to achieve would be to annotate your data with some runtime type information when it is saved by the form (e.g. something like `{ "__type": "string", "value: null }`, or alternatively have your form directly save the data in memory using the format you require.

Comment: so there's no way for, at compile time, Typescript to see that I want to check every attribute on an object and do A if string and B if number?

I can manually do a hardcode if(property == "Property A") all the way down but that's both terrible code and I'd have to manually update it if I ever add attributes to this class (which I definitely will in the future)

Comment: No. If I understand you correctly, this is not possible.

Comment: so how do people typically handle this sort of thing? What do I do now

Comment: Does the second paragraph of my answer not answer that question already?

Comment: That would work for a quick hack but I'm trying to get as close to a "best practice" solution as I can. I'll probably end up writing a helper method in my object class that sets all my number attributes that are null to 0, but every option I have here seems awful and bad

Comment: You can call them "quick hacks" if you want, but just to reiterate what I said, they are the *only way* to do what you want to do in TypeScript. You will somehow need to encode the information at the point they are saved by the form. How you do that is up to you.